# Back button not appearing in Metro style app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have followed the tutorial on MSDN. The default back button for html/javascript metro style apps does not appear anywhere.

I then created new projects (grid app, blank app, navigation app) and even though it is defined in code, it does not display. However, other apps that have been installed from the Windows Store all display the back button.

Anybody else having this issue with the back button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>homePage</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>

    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/pages/home/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/pages/home/home.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
    <div class="fragment homepage">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Dude!</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you've already tried this, but the HTML by itself won't be enough.  The button added by the templates requires JavaScript to enable the back button.

By default, the button is added with the `disabled` attribute set, but script removes that attribute if it determines there's something to navigate back to.

For example, here's the relevant part from the Grid app template (in /js/navigator.js):

```
        // This function updates application controls once a navigation
        // has completed.
        navigated: function () {
            // Do application specific on-navigated work here
            var backButton = this.pageElement.querySelector("header[role=banner] .win-backbutton");
            if (backButton) {
                backButton.onclick = function () { nav.back(); };

                if (nav.canGoBack) {
                    backButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
                } else {
                    backButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        },
```

You can see it looks for the back button by class `.win-backbutton` and, if `nav.canGoBack` is true, enables the back button by, er, removing the disabling. :)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the detailed answer @Chris, much appreciated. :)